# Using Nonce with Ajax in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, jquery, nonce

I'm trying to use a nonce in a WordPress plugin. I've got a form that I want use the nonce on.

In php:

```
function csf_enqueue() {

//I have other scripts enqueued in htis function 
wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'file-path', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'google-maps'));

$data = array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'my_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('myajax-nonce')
);

wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', $data );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'csf_enqueue');
add_action('wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function');
```

In the jQuery file:

```
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, {my_nonce : the_ajax_script.my_nonce}, jQuery("#theForm").serialize() + "&maxLat="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[0] + "&maxLong="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[1] + "&minLat="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[2] + "&minLong="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[3],
                    function(response_from_the_action_function){
                        jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
                    });
```

Am I posting the nonce correctly in the jQuery?

In php:

```
function the_action_function() {
   if( ! wp_verfiy_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-nonce')) die ('Busted!');
//function continues
```

Any suggestions? If I strip out all the code regarding the nonce, everything works fine. Any ideas as to why it's not working? Or how can I debug it? Thank you!

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things wrong.

Sending data via jQuery post method, you can not send one object+one query string as you have done. Instead you will need to either send the query string format or the object format data. For ease in your case, I will go with the query string format. so the post code should look like this

```
jQuery.post( the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, 
             jQuery("#theForm").serialize() + 
                    "&maxLat="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[0] + 
                    "&maxLong="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[1] + 
                    "&minLat="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[2] + 
                    "&minLong="+ csf_dcscore_crime_map_bounds[3] +
                    "&my_nonce="+ the_ajax_script.my_nonce,
             function(response_from_the_action_function) {
                 jQuery("#response_area")
                     .html(response_from_the_action_function);
             });
```

That will send the nonce in the parameter my_nonce. Now server side you can replace

```
if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-nonce')) die ('Busted!');
```

with

```
if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_nonce'],'myajax-nonce')) die ('Busted!');
```

A look at the documentation of [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [wp_verfiy_nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce) will help you better :)

Comment: Hi sbrajesh, Thank you very much for your help. I made the changes to the code that you suggested. I also removed the underscore in 'ajaxurl'. Unfortunately, I'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_verfiy_nonce()". Sounds like the function isn't loaded in time for some reason. Any ideas? Thank you !

Comment: I had a misspelling in wp_verify_nonce, too. Bad typing. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it is working. If it does not
change

    ` $data = array(
     'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
     'my_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('myajax-nonce')
    );`
to

   ` $data = array(
     'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
     'my_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('myajax-nonce')
    );
`
 

or replace `ajaxurl` in my code with `ajax_url` as you have in data